# Can Class<V> take multiple bounds on the generic type?

Tags: java, generics

The following code compiles:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClassTest
{
  private ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1>> testClass = 
    new ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1>>();

  private interface Interface1 {}
}
```

But the following code produces six errors:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClassTest
{
  private ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1 & Interface2>> testClass = 
    new ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1 & Interface2>>();

  private interface Interface1 {}
  private interface Interface2 {}
}
```

Errors:

```
ClassTest.java:5: > expected
  private ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1 & Interface2>> testClass = 
                                              ^
ClassTest.java:5: ';' expected
  private ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1 & Interface2>> testClass = 
                                                           ^
ClassTest.java:5: <identifier> expected
  private ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1 & Interface2>> testClass = 
                                                                       ^
ClassTest.java:6: > expected
    new ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1 & Interface2>>();
                                            ^
ClassTest.java:6: '(' or '[' expected
    new ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1 & Interface2>>();
                                               ^
ClassTest.java:6: illegal start of expression
    new ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1 & Interface2>>();
                                                            ^
```

It's pretty clear that the compiler isn't recognizing the `&` being used for multiple generic bounds on `Class`.  Are you not allowed multiple bounds on the type parameter for `Class`?  What am I supposed to do if I want an `ArrayList` of `Class`es that implement both `Interface1` and `Interface2`?

**Motivation:** The code I'm working on at the moment has a lot of declarations like this:

```
private static HashMap<String, Class<? extends ApproximativeMode>> approximativeMethod = 
new HashMap<String, Class<? extends ApproximativeMode>>();
```

They map a string to a class which contains a 'method' for doing a certain calculation.  Each separate hashmap uses a different wildcard for the classes (so `ApproximativeMode` might be replaced with `ExactMode` for the hashmap containing all of the exact methods).

I've just gone through all of the methods, making them implement a new interface, `NamedMethod`,  which has a method that gets their full, displayed name (e.g. "Linear hydroxyadenine method").  I now want to put all of the hashmaps into an `ArrayList` so that I can write an iterator that goes over the hashmaps and displays their full names.  So I might end up with:

**Approximative Methods**

von Ahsen et al.

Owen et al.

etc.

**Exact Methods**

Santalucia et al.

LHM

etc.

etc.

So my declaration of the `ArrayList` holding all the hashmaps is:

```
private ArrayList<Hashmap<String, Class<? extends NamedMethod>>> namedMethods;
```

Of course, none of the hashmaps are actually of that type, but I was hoping that I could add `NamedMethod` to the wildcard in each one and get an `ArrayList` of them all.  Clearly that isn't possible.

If this isn't clear, let me know and I'll fix it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Wildcard bounds vs Type parameter bounds:**

- You can't have multiple bounds on wildcards. You can only have them for type parameters.
- Another difference is, you can have upper and lower bounds for wildcards, but there is no lower bound for type parameter.

So, as per the 1<sup>st</sup> difference, if you want to have multiple bounds, then you have to use type parameter declared with your class. That means, you have to make the class generic itself. And then the interfaces should be declared separately as top-level interface:

```
public class ClassTest<T extends Interface1 & Interface2> {
    private ArrayList<Class<T>> testClass = new ArrayList<Class<T>>();    
}

interface Interface1 {}
interface Interface2 {}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `<? extends ...` and `<T extends...`

Comment: There is a difference in how and where you can use wildcards and type parameters.

Comment: @Rohit Thanks, but that would only allow me to instantiate the class `ClassTest` with a *particular* class satisfying the bounds, and then create an `ArrayList` of *that class*.  What if I want an `ArrayList` with many different classes in it, all of which implement two given interfaces?

Comment: @Donkey_2009. Can you specify your requirement, as to what you are trying to do and why? What is the use case? May be there is some other way out

Comment: @Donkey_2009. So, your `NamedMethod` class is a super interface of `ApproximationMode` and `ExactMode`?

Comment: @Rohit No it's not.  `ApproximationMode`, `ExactMode` etc. are not all interfaces.  Some of them are classes, some are interfaces, and none of them implement or extend `NamedMethod`.  But all the classes that go into the hashmap implement `NamedMethod` as well as extending/implementing the specified class/interface.

Comment: @Donkey_2009. Can't you change your `HashMap`s to `HashMap<String, Class<? extends NamedMethod>> map`?

Comment: @Rohit I can't tell you without looking into where they're used in the program.  But I suspect that, for example, the method which reads values from the `ApproximativeMode` hashmap then instantiates those classes and calls methods from the `ApproximativeMode` class.

Comment: @Rohit I've looked into the code now: methods aren't called from the `ApproximativeMode` class, but they are called from an interface that it implements. The `NamedMethod` interface isn't really central to the program; it's just a way of getting the name off the top layer of classes.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Since I'm using reflection anyway (the `Class` objects) I'm going to try and go with the `isAssignableFrom()` method to check that they implement the `NamedMethod` interface.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Yes of course that is an option. I'm trying to get my head around this problem, but can't really reach a solution. Perhaps it's not possible to do it without some check with your current design. Anyways, you're welcome :)

Comment: `instanceof` won't work. You would use `isAssignableFrom` for `Class` instances.

Comment: @Rohit.  Sorry - that was a momentary mistake, and I've corrected it now.  Yeah, I think I'm going to have to go with the check for now.  Some day I'll sit down and rewrite this horrible, horrible codebase from scratch.